# Prove two algorithms are identical

Tags: algorithm, logic, tail-recursion, eiffel

I am supposed to show that two algorithms execute identical statements in identical order. One is a tail recursive version of the other. They are written in Eiffel.

```
tail_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    local
        y:instance_type;
    do
        if b(x) then
            Result :=c(x)
        else
            y:=d(x);
            Result:=tail_rec(y)
    end
  end
```

Then the non-tail recursive version.

```
non_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    do
        from until b(x) loop
            x:= d(x)
        end;
        Result:= c(x)
    end
```

where b(x), c(x), and d(x) are any functions of type BOOLEAN, result_type, and instance_type respectively.

How are these two algorithms similar and how do they execute identical statements in identical order?

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  This does not look like two different algorithms to me.  It looks like the exact same algorithm implemented twice in two functions with identical bodies and different names.

Comment: @MikeNakis Like its said, one is tail recursive version of the other            Edit: Actually you were right. Changed it to what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By substituting all flow-of-control constructs with `goto`s, (essentially turning the code from `Eiffel` into pseudocode,) and allowing `if` statements to execute only `goto`s, it can be shown that both functions end up consisting of the exact same set of instructions.

Let me begin by copying the original `tail_rec` here for convenience:

```
tail_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    local
        y:instance_type;
    do
        if b(x) then
            Result := c(x)
        else
            y := d(x);
            Result := tail_rec(y)
        end
    end
```

First, get rid of Eiffel's silly `Result :=` construct and replace it with `return` for convenience.  (Otherwise, we are going to have to add more `goto`s, and frankly, the fewer the better.)

```
tail_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    local
        y:instance_type;
    do
        if b(x) then
            return c(x)
        end
        y := d(x);
        return tail_rec(y)
    end
```

Substitute the `if`-`then`-`end` with `if`-`then goto`:

```
tail_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    local
        y:instance_type;
    do
        if not b(x) then goto label1
        return c(x)
    label1:
        y := d(x);
        return tail_rec(y)
    end
```

Replace tail recursion with another `goto`:

```
tail_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    do
    label0:
        if not b(x) then goto label1
        return c(x)
    label1:
        x := d(x);
        goto label0
    end
```

Replace `if not b(x)` with `if b(x)`:

```
tail_rec(x:instance_type):result_type is
    do
    label0:
        if b(x) then goto label1
        x := d(x);
        goto label0
    label1:
        return c(x)
    end
```

Similar transformations to `tail_rec` should turn it into the exact same thing.